# How do I sort a resultant list in Prolog?

Tags: sorting, prolog

So I've got these predicates,

```
isSorted([]).
isSorted([_]).
isSorted([A,B|L]) :- A =< B, isSorted([B|L]).

toEven([], L2) :- isSorted(L2); sort(L2, OP), write(OP), toEven([], OP).
toEven([F|L1], [DUB|L2]) :- F mod 2 =\= 0, DUB is 2 * F, toEven(L1, L2).
toEven([F|L1], [F|L2]) :- F mod 2 =:= 0, toEven(L1, L2).
```

where `toEven(L, X)` doubles any odd numbers inputted in order to achieve a completely even list.

Currently, inputting `toEven([1,2,3,4,5], X)` returns a correct result of `X = [2, 2, 6, 4, 10]`, but my attempt to sort the list seems to be having no effect. I would've thought in the base case it would check if `L2` is sorted and if not sort and call toEven() with the sorted result instead.

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong with this? I've been trying to figure it out with trace to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue with your implementation is that it only outputs the result, via `write`, if the list is not sorted when it's created:

```
toEven([], L2) :- isSorted(L2) ; sort(L2, OP), write(OP), toEven([], OP).
```

If `isSorted(L2)` succeeds, then `toEven([], L2)` concludes successfully without any further action (no output via `write`).

In Prolog, it's best to generate results are arguments, not with `write`. It's also probably just as efficient to sort the list unconditionally, even if it's already sorted, since your check to see if it's already sorted costs something and has to recurse the entire list and do a comparison on each element. You also want to be careful with `sort/2`... it removes duplicates. Use `msort/2` if you want to keep duplicates.

Wrapping all that up:

```
toEven(L, LEven) :-
    toEvenAux(L, LEvenUnsorted),
    msort(LEvenUnsorted, LEven).

toEvenAux([], []).
toEvenAux([F|L1], [DUB|L2]) :- F mod 2 =\= 0, DUB is 2 * F, toEvenAux(L1, L2).
toEvenAux([F|L1], [F|L2]) :- F mod 2 =:= 0, toEvenAux(L1, L2).
```

Comment: This approach worked for me, thanks. To fit what I specified I put the auxiliary function first followed by the `msort/2` on `LSorted`. The print statements I included were only part of my attempt to debug.

Comment: @Jozef makes sense. :) Note in Prolog they're called *predicates* not *functions*. They don't behave the same way.